# Map Eigen replicate Matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, replicate

I am trying to bring code from Matlab to C++. There is some information related to my case [in the KDE Eigen Forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=90876).

What I try to achieve is related to Matlab's meshgrid, for which the solution given over there is

```
X = RowVectorXd::LinSpaced(1,3,3).replicate(5,1);
Y = VectorXd::LinSpaced(10,14,5).replicate(1,3);
```

i.e., `.replicate` the vectors the amount of the other dimension. In my case I have two existing (n x 1) vectors and want to create a (n^2, 2) matrix which contains all combinations of vector elements, that is:

```
[1 3 6]^T and [7 8]^T ==> [1 7, 3 7, 6 7, 1 8, 3 8, 6 8]^T
```

where `^T` just means transposed, lines are comma-separated. (In my case the vectors use floats, but that shouldn't matter).

The first column of the matrix `[1 3 6 1 3 6]^T` is easily created by Eigen's `.replicate` function. However, I struggle to create the second column `[7 7 7 8 8 8]^T`.

My idea was to use `.replicate` in the other dimension (obtaining a matrix) and then use a rowWise `Eigen::Map` to bring it to a linear (vector) view (as suggested [in the docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html)), but I understand the arising compiler error such that `Eigen::Map` doesn't work with an `Eigen::Replicate` type.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    MatrixXd reptest1(1, 5);
    reptest1 << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
    auto result2 = reptest1.replicate(2, 1); // cols, rows: 5, 2
    auto result3 = Map<Matrix<double, 1, Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> >(result2);  // this doesn't work
return 0;
}
```

VS2017 complains: `error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'Eigen::Replicate<Derived,-1,-1>' to 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,-1,1,1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>'`
GCC also complains. `no matching function for call` (can't copy&paste exact message as it is on another machine).

Am I doing this too complicated? Should using Map work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` can only work on matrices, not on expressions. So replace `auto result2` by `MatrixXd result2`, and you're done. See [common pitfalls](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

Comment: Thank you for that extraordinarily quick answer. However, even without auto it doesn't work `MatrixXd result2 = reptest1.replicate(2, 1); // cols, rows: 5, 2 VectorXd result3 = Map<Matrix<double, 1, Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> >(result2);`

Comment: `Map<RowVectorXd> resultAsCol(result2.data(), result2.size());`
seems to do what I want. I accept your answer and thanks to the link to the common pitfalls. Have overlooked it and this is important to know as I usually try to embrace C++11 and C++14 as much as possible.

Comment: Right, I overlooked this second mistake.